# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream in WP7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

Im trying to get Images from URL and store it within my isolated storage, and then get the images from the isolated storage
here is my relevant code:

```
public void GetImages()
{
    string uri = "http://sherutnetphpapi.cloudapp.net/mini_logos/" + path;
    WebClient m_webClient = new WebClient();
    imageUri = new Uri(uri);   
    m_webClient.OpenReadAsync(imageUri);
    m_webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted);
    m_webClient.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;  
}

void webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string iso_path = "~/SherutApp1;component/" + path;
    var isolatedfile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(iso_path, FileMode.Create, isolatedfile))                                                                    
    {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
        while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

i get the exception at the headline on this line:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(iso_path, FileMode.Create, isolatedfile))
```

I don't know what is the problem, although i think that maybe  images does not inserted correctly to the isolated storage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the `"~/SherutApp1;component/"` part in there. If you the entire path is `"test.jpg"` or `"folderThatExists\\test.jpg"` it should work.

Comment: the path is the name of the company.png, for example: "bezeq.png"

Comment: i tried to run it without the "/SherutApp1;component/" and it doesn't make any change.....

Comment: What is the value of your path variable at that using statement?

Comment: name of the current company.png , for example: "bezeq.png"